# How to bind multiple (Asp. Button Or Html Button) Dynamically using InnerHtml With OnClick Event in ASp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

Need to add multiple buttons (Asp.Button or Html Button With Click Event) Dynamically With Help of Using InnerHtml, but the button not visible in the Screen,
[image]
but I try to add the same Button code to Directly apply to the Div It's Di[![enter image description here]splaying Fine With Click Event,
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the most part, with asp.net webforms, the design pattern and approach is NOT like most other systems in which they often write code to “inject” HTML on a page.

You “can” do the above, but in 99% of cases, you don’t do that, you don’t need to, and you don’t want to.
You see, at the end of the day, you saying you want to add button.

But REALLY one probably means you have some “rows” of data or “row” of a “thing” you want to repeat over and over.

And for each thing, not only will you want a button, ,but also code that operates on that one row. Again, 9 out of 10 times, you not REALLY wanting JUST a button, but a button along with some information.

And clicking on that button should operate on that ONE thing.
In other words, with 10 rows, and 10 buttons, do you want to try and write all that code, and THEN figure out what button you clicked on???
So, really, the problem + solution is to build one thing, drop it on the page, and then “add” a new row to that “thing”, and it will show the button + text, or whatever you want.
The huge “bonus” part is now when you click on a row, it can operate on that one row, and the code is all the same for 2 rows, or 20 rows.
The above is the “essence” of how asp.net works. This is un-like many other systems (such as the popular PHP – where often you write looping code to repeat information on the screen).
So, lets build something that lets us add a new row, and that new row will have a text box, and a button. Heck, lets toss in a radio button list choice – and repeat that too!
The cool concept here is that we can drop more controls into that “repeater”, and we don’t have to write really much more code to “repeat” over and over that one thing.
And when we click on that button, then we get/have the information about that one row.
So, I VERY much doubt ALL you want is a simple button, and no doubt will want to repeat MORE then just a button.

So, to “repeat” things on a web page, then an appropriate choice is a “repeater” (seems to have the right name, don’t you think???).

So, we can now have this really simple markup. Only the button and the text box – and only have to drop that text box and button ONE time onto the page.

We then let asp.net do its magic, and maintain, and allow us to have 2 or 20 rows. And in the future, we can feed this “thing” data from a database (so, when you return to the page, it can remember and display what you have!!).
I mean it is VERY unlikely that you going to say have 5 rows, and then tomorrow when you return to the page, everything is gone? Now how you going to re-inject the “rows” that you had?
(again, think of this problem not in web + html markup, but as a “thing” you want to repeat over and over, and no doubt want to “save” this information.).
So, the REAL challenge is not placing a button on the page, but management of this WHOLE problem in a way that does not break the bank in the amount of code you have to write here.
I mean, if  you manage to inject 5 rows/5 buttons, then how are you going to manage this 5 sets of whatever it is you want? And how will you return to that page to re-edit, or change or even just display that information again?
Just code to inject one button gains and gets you quite much nothing of use here.
Ok, so, lets drop in our ONE button, text box, and even for bonus points, drop in a readio button choice.

So, lets drop in a button to “add” the markup, including that button.
Below that, we will have the markup we want to repeat (like the button etc.).

So, our button:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdNew" runat="server" Text="Add new" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdNew_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <br />
```

Ok, that will "add our button" (and whatever else we want ALONG with that button!!!).

So, now below above, we have this:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="float: left">
                    Comic:<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComic" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("Comic") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left: 14px">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Rating:<br />
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rRating" runat="server"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="8"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Rating") %>' >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Poor"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Good"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Excellent"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="New in Bag"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both">

                    Notes:<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server"
                        TextMode="MultiLine" Height="119px" Width="328px"
                        Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>'
                        ></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:Button ID="cmdRow" runat="server" Text="View" style="margin-left:8px"
                        OnClick="cmdRow_Click" CssClass="btn"
                        />
                </div>
                <hr / style="border:solid 1px">
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
```

Now, we in code create the "thing" we want to repeat.

so, this code:

```
    public class ComicBook
    {
        public string Comic { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }


    List<ComicBook> MyComics = new List<ComicBook>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void cmdNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetExistingRows();
        ComicBook NewComic = new ComicBook();
        NewComic.Rating = "Poor";
        MyComics.Add(NewComic);
        Repeater1.DataSource = MyComics;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    void GetExistingRows()
    {
        foreach(RepeaterItem OneRow in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            ComicBook OneComic = new ComicBook();
            OneComic.Comic = ((TextBox)OneRow.FindControl("txtComic")).Text;
            OneComic.Rating = ((RadioButtonList)OneRow.FindControl("rRating")).SelectedItem.Text;
            OneComic.Comments = ((TextBox)OneRow.FindControl("txtComments")).Text;
            MyComics.Add(OneComic);
        }

    }

    protected void cmdRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        Debug.Print("Row click = " + rRow.ItemIndex);
        TextBox txtComic = (TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtComic");
        Debug.Print("Comic name = "+ txtComic.Text);
        
    }
```

Note how there is NOT a bunch of html injection code in above.

so, now when we run, we get this:

[image]

but, EVEN better, is note the button click event!!!

When we click that "view" button, we now can get information about the ONE row we clicked on.

If I click view on the 2nd set of controls, then output is this:

output:

```
Row click = 1   (row number is zero based)
Comic name = Spider man
```

So, now if I add 2 or 8, then note how I don't write more code, I don't have to write loops to inject markup, and I also as huge bonus have a button click wired up that allows operations on the "repeated" thing.

So, don't try to inject the button. Design your task/problem based on the concept of "what" it is you need/want to repeat.

And it turns out this approach is VERY database friendly, so we could in place of the above (using the page viewstate) use a database for each thing we "add", and thus the code to repeat and display information when we return to that page next day is ALSO really quite much already written for us.